# How to import script from top layer which is not in a package?

Tags: python, import

I got a project structure looking like this:

```
main_project/
├── config.py
├── __init__.py
├── src
    └── package
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module.py
```

In `config.py` is a class named `Config()`.
I want to import `Config()` in `module.py`. When I run `module.py` from the top of the project, I get an ImportError for trying to import `Config()` with: `from config import Config`.

How do I do this correctly without moving `config.py` into another python package?
Thank you!

Comment: Can we see the `config.py` file here? From your description, this should be working. I'm thinking something else may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Within `module.py`, try this:

```
import config
```

Now, from `module.py`, you should be able to access `Config()` like so:

```
x = config.Config()
```

**EDIT**: For what it's worth, this does work for me:
[image]
This will run, and print "test me out".

I think that something else might be going on here. Can we see `config.py`?

**Another edit for clarity**:

`config.py` and the other `__init__.py` are not in the `src/` folder, but PyCharm makes it look like it could be. Pic related:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work either, it doesn't find main_project as a module

Comment: I tried, but I got the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
`. It's there where it tries to just `import config`

Comment: Oh I see why it works for you. Your `config.py` is in `src`, but mine is in `testproject`.

Comment: It's not in `src`, it's just how PyCharm is displaying it.

Comment: Well then I'm clueless :D

Comment: @Lady_Hangaku Maybe we take a look at `config.py`? Perhaps there is just a silly typo in the class name? The simplest things can have you scratching your head for hours, sometimes!

Comment: So what I just did is adding a "run_module_function.py" in the top-level, so now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/../../main_project/')
import config
```

Comment: Which app folder is meant by that? Should I write '../../config.py'?

Comment: Just the folder which contains the config.py so '/../../main_project/'

Comment: Tried it out, but it doesn't want to work, either. Also tried to use slashes in the front and back and without them.

Comment: And you did 'import config' not 'import file' right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to check how python search the file when import. Python will search file below the directory in `sys.path` list .

In module.py

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

When you run module.py from the top of the project, you will see the output like that.

```
['/Users/vstorm/PycharmProjects/main_project/src/package', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

There is no `'/Users/vstorm/PycharmProjects/main_project`, so if you use `from config import Config`, it won't search `config` in `main_project` directory，so it raise the error.

@fames's solution should work.